# Dropdown menu flickering when I hover over it

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an e-commerce website for practicing, but I ran into a problem. I made a dropdown menu for the first item in a nav bar, but when I hover over it, the whole menu keeps flickering.

I have tried everything up to my knowledge of css and html, and no good. Mind you, I'm only a beginner.

```css
.cabecalho {
 background-color: #22333B;
 display: flex;
 border-bottom: 6px solid black;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 20px;
}

.cabecalho-nav { 
 width: 400px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 position: relative;
 right:20px;
}

.dropdown-categorias {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 3px;
 top: 30px;
 background-color: #22333B;
 min-width: 120px;
  z-index: 1; 
}

.dropdown-categorias a {
 border: 2px solid black;
 color: white;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 8px;
 font-size: .8rem;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown-categorias a:nth-child(1){
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.dropdown-categorias a:nth-child(2){
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.dropdown-categorias a:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

#texto-categoria:hover+.dropdown-categorias{ 
  display:block
}
```

```html
<nav class="cabecalho-nav">
  <a class="texto-nav" id="texto-categoria">Categorias</a>
  <div class="dropdown-categorias">
    <a href="eletronicos.html">Eletronicos</a>
    <a href="acessorios.html">Acessórios</a>
    <a href="arte.html">Musica</a>
  </div>
  <a href="test.html" class="texto-nav">Home</a>
  <a href="sobre.html" class="texto-nav">Sobre</a>
  <a href="contato.html" class="texto-nav">Contato</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flickering is happening because once the menu pops you're no longer hovering over the categories link. I believe you can accomplish what you're trying to do by adjusting the classes below to what I have provided:

```
.dropdown-categorias a {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #22333B;
}

#texto-categoria:hover+.dropdown-categorias, .dropdown-categorias:hover{ 
  display:block;
}

.dropdown-categorias {
  background: none;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

example: https://js-mj45kn.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I've been stuck on this for quite some time now.                                                        
                                                           
It's funny cause I made a dropdown menu before, for this same website, and it worked just fine

Comment: No problem! Please accept this as the answer so others know what solution worked for you.